# What is the best way to validate the same bean for multiple use cases in java/spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

**TL;DR:  From the "clean code" point of view, what is the best way to implement validation for any object for different use cases?**

**To clarify, suppose I have this entity:**

```
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    
    private String username;

    //getters, setters ...

}
```

**and this service class (it could be an interface also):**

```
public class UserService{
    public void createUser(User user){
        //...
    }

    public void updateUser(User user){
       //...
    }
}
```

**and these 2 use cases:**

**1.** **Create user** ( id must be null and username must be a valid username)

**2.** **Update user** ( id must be valid id and username must be valid username)

- **First Approach (the NAIVE way):** put validation logic for each use case inside the service method. ex:

  ```
  public void createUser(User user){
              //validation logic here
              //other business logic
          }
  ```

- **Second Approach (use annotations):**
  use hibernate's out-of-the-box annotations (`@NotNull`, `@Null`, ...)    or [hibernate custom annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints) (for example in    this case I can    create an annotation `@Username` which validates a    username according    to my app needs).
  In this case the `User` looks like:
  public class User {

  ```
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @Username
  private String username;

  //getters, setters ...
  }
  //and the service methods will have `@Valid` before the parameters to    be validated:
  public class UserService{
      public void createUser(@Valid User user){
          //...
      }

      public void updateUser(@Valid User user){
         //...
      }
  }
  ```

**Problem here is that same validation logic is applied for both use cases create and update, which is not what my requirements above imply.**

- **Third Approach ( use annotations with validation groups for each use case):**

  ```
    public class User {

          @Id(OnUpdate.class)
          @Null(OnCreate.class)
          private Integer id;

          @Username //no need to specify groups bcz this field has same validation logic for all cases
          private String username;

          //getters, setters ...

      }
  ```

  **problem here is that the entity now [violates the Single Responsibility Principle and knows how it will be used in different
  cases](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-anti-patterns).**
- **Fourth Approach (call the validator manually):**

  Same as First approach but validation logic not put in service
  method, however I call the `Validator` manually from the service
  method:

  ```
  public class UserService{
      public void createUser(User user){
          //call validator.validate(user) here
          //other business logic
      }

      public void updateUser(User user){
         //call validator.validate(user) here
         //other business logic
      }
  }
  ```

  **n.b.: User is annotated as in Third Approach i.e. using validation
  groups**
- **Last Approach:**

  Use the functional programming types : `Either`, `Right`, `Left`,
  `ValueObject` (we can get their implementations from a dependency
  like [vavr.io](https://www.vavr.io/) as they are not supported yet out-of-the-box)

  ```
  abstract class ValueObject<L,R>{
      Either<L,R> value;
      //L (left) for storing invalid value
      //R (right) for storing valid value
  }

  class UsernameVO extends ValueObject<ValueFailure<String>,String>{
      private UsernameVO(Either<ValueFailure<String>,String> value){
          this.value = value;
      }

      public static UsernameVO create(String name){
          //factory method calls the private constructor
          //...
      }

      //other private methods for validation
  }

  class ValueFailure<T>{
      String reason;
      T failedValue;
      //getters, setters...
  }
  ```

  So now we have a field `UsernameVO username` in the `User` and not a
  simple `String username`

  In this case service looks like:

  ```
     public class UserService{
         public void createUser(User user){
             //use "fold" method on each Either type to validate it
             user
             .usernameVO.
             .value
             .fold(stringValueFailure -> {
                  //throw error
              },
              validValue -> {
                  //do nothing
                  return null;
              });
         }

         public void updateUser(User user){
            //same as above
         }
     }
  ```

Comment: In most cases [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) used for this.

Comment: @VictorGubin yes I see, but notice the problem in the third approach, which is justifiable in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

There is no best way for all use cases of bean validation. You need to weigh the pros and cons. Violating the single responsibility principle for the example you have given should not cause too much of a problem.
But if your bean validation has more than 2/3 different cases and also the entity is bigger, then I'll suggest the following approach.

```
public class User {

    // Add hibernate annotations only for the common cases. 

    private Integer id; 

    @UserName  
    private String username;

    //getters, setters ...
}
```

Then use the following class for more comprehensive validations.

```
public class UserValidator {

    public static final int CREATE = 0;
    public static final int UPDATE = 1;
    // and so on ...

    public static void validate(User user, int useCase) throws Exception{

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
        if (!violations.isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("User object failed base validations");

        switch (useCase){
            case CREATE:
                createCase(user);
                break;
            case UPDATE:
                updateCase(user);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void createCase(User user) throws Exception{
        //additional validations for this use case
    }

    public static void updateCase(User user)throws Exception{
       //additional validations for this use case
    }

    // add similar functions for different cases ...
}
```

And the service class will look like -

```
public class UserService{
    public void createUser(User user){
        UserValidator.validate(user, UserValidator.CREATE);
        //...
    }

    public void updateUser(User user){
       UserValidator.validate(user, UserValidator.UPDATE);
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: similar to fourth and last approach, I agree with that there is no unique solution for all cases, but there must be some guidelines/rules to tell you when to use which solution

Comment: Yes, this is kind of a mixture of different approaches. Although I didn't know about vavr.io dependency approach before. Also, I don't really think there will be any sort of well-known guidelines/rules for bean validations apart from some advice and suggestions. I think you'll have to make your own rules.